# how to create a token for new customer using stripe.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Stripe documentation says that the following code can be used to create a new customer.

```
stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'Customer for test@example.com',
  source: "tok_16cz9QDmMHdxsE7ezNjoLsUM" // obtained with Stripe.js
}, function(err, customer) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

But Stripe.js does not say how to create a token for a customer. Does any one know how to create a token for new customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it does](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_card_token); the docs clearly state that customer-based token creation is only possible for Stripe Connect and "can only be used with an OAuth access token or Stripe-Account header." In that context, you can pass a `customer` attribute. In any other context, you can only create tokens based on cards or bank accounts.

Comment: I confused little-bit, [Create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer) page says that `stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'Customer for test@example.com',
  source: "tok_XXXXXXX" // obtained with Stripe.js
}, function(err, customer) {
  // asynchronously called
});` **obtained with Stripe.js**. Then I searched for creating token for a customer using Stripe.js.

Comment: The token in that context is just a card token not a customer token. That card token is just a token you get by providing Stripe.js credit card details, since your server should not access card info.